# How to send messages notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am searching for an hour for a way to do that(without Parse because it's going down this month).

I am trying to do in the app that one user can send push notification message to another specific user.

What are the options to implement that?(please be specific)

Thanks.

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Cloud Messaging. See https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example

Comment: How can I use FCM in my project? the github project you gave me is messy and has errors.... @AL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is not typically recommended, as it can very easily become problematic. Techincally, users should not be able to send direct push notifications to other users. All notifications should be handled through a central system that wouldn't be accessible to your individual users. However, if you feel that you'd still like to make this work, read on.

I have a mechanism like this in one of my apps, using FCM. Here's the function (with some modifications to take out my specific information) that I use to send messages from one user to another:

```
func push(message: String, toUser: String) {
    var token: String?
    for person in self.users {
        if toUser == person.username && person.firebaseToken != nil {
            token = person.firebaseToken
        }
    }
    if token != nil {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=[your FCM Server Key]", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let json = [
            "to" : token!,
            "priority" : "high",
            "notification" : [
                "body" : message
            ]
        ] as [String : Any]
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    print("Error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                    // check for http errors
                    print("Status Code should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("Response = \(response)")
                }

                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I keep this method in my appDelegate, and call it whenever necessary. Basically, every user in my app has a Firebase messaging token assigned to them, and it's just another property of each user. You can get a user's FCM token with this call:

```
let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
```

Usually, the token can be retrieved and saved when a user first creates an account. The token will remain the same as long as the user uses the same device.

Again, this can be very dangerous if it is implemented without proper security measures to prevent your users from having total control over sending push notifications.

Comment: Would it be good to use that method to send to a lot of users at once? actually I am trying that one user can send to a bunch of other people push.(like whatsapp group). What should I do? Use this method?

Comment: Yes, you can still use this. I use it regularly to send messages to groups of people. Just use a for-loop and continue calling this method as many times as you need.

Comment: You wrote there "your FCM app code here", I add Firebase to my app but where can I find this FCM code?

Comment: In your Firebase database, if you go to your app's settings, you'll see a tab "Cloud Messaging". It's the server key there.

Comment: I see, ans it's running! BUT it didn't send push and throws Status Code should be 200, but is 401
Response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6080000296a0> { URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send } { status code: 401, headers {
What is it? How to fix that?

Comment: Make sure that it is your server key, and not your web API key, that you put in the HTTP header. The server key is on the Cloud Messaging tab, that's the one you need to use.

Comment: OK it worked! BUT it has no sound and budget  to it.. Why is the notification without any sound?

Comment: I don't usually use sounds in my notifications, but you should be able to by adding another parameter in the notifcation dictionary in the JSON. Check out this link for more information on adding other parameters (including sounds) to your FCM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Comment: Ok I understand, and it worked. BUT(again) How can I save the data to the device without saving it to the server? Is there an option?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What data are you looking to save to the device?

Comment: Look, here is my problem: I want that only users that have a specific password will be allowed to send push to other people. So I have a list of X number of users and under them the device token. Then only everyone else that type the password 1234 can send too. How can I accomplish that with high level of security? BTW you are really helpful I appreciate it dude!

Comment: Hi, I have an issue: I want that after the user got the notification the device will save this text of the notification to its own memory immediately, How can I accomplish that?

Comment: In your appDelegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification, you can write the text of the message to UserDefaults or to a plist on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this.
Although the status code is 200, I can't see any notification.

This is the return value.

```
{
    \"multicast_id\":6666941437973455953,
    \"success\":1,
    \"failure\":0,
    \"canonical_ids\":0,
    \"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1490256129594240%03b6b50f03b6b50f\"}]
}
```